# How to make the constructor display the selected image?

Tags: c#, wpf

What should I write in this constructor in order to display the image selected from the previous list.

```
public SelectionDisplay(object label, Brush background)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
```

For example, if I choose the koala (see pic1) from the image list, a new window should open with the wide image of the koala and a short description. I tried to be as clear as possible; I've also posted the code that generates images.

```
 private void KinectTileButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var button = (KinectTileButton)e.Source;
        var image = button.CommandParameter as BitmapImage;
        var selectionDisplay = new SelectionDisplay(button.Label,button.Background); // aici poti apoi sa mai trimiti si imaginea ca parametru pentru constructor
        this.kinectRegionGrid.Children.Add(selectionDisplay);
        e.Handled = true;

    }
```

> ```
>             var files = Directory.GetFiles(@".\GalleryImages");
> ```

```
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);

                BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                bi.BeginInit();
                bi.UriSource = new Uri(file, UriKind.Relative);
                bi.EndInit();

                var button = new KinectTileButton
                {
                    Label = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file),
                    Background = new ImageBrush(bi),
                    Tag = file
                };
                var selectionDisplay = new SelectionDisplay(button.Label as string, button.Tag as string);
                this.wrapPanel.Children.Add(button);
```

http://i57.tinypic.com/2liegrk.png

Answer (score 0):

Can you please rephrase your requirement?
What I get is that you have a list of some images and probably some description and as soon as you click one of the image it opens up wide on a new screen. You want to execute  this functionality through the constructor of your view model. Please confirm if this is the correct understanding.

Comment: I have a list o images that can be seen in the previous image. When the user clicks on an image, a new window should open, in which the selected image and its respective description should be displayed.

Comment: so if my assumption is correct you're having this image and description in Dictionary object?